# Error while opening file in VS2010 Beta 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I installed VS2010 B2 on my Win 7 machine. I create a simple DLL project and try to open the file Class1.cs that gets created by Default. I get a error message "The operation could not be completed. Invalid Pointer. So far i have seen this and similar error messages on previous versions of VS2010. Anyone else faced and solved this problem?

Answer: It seems i have to use true type fonts. The moment i changed the editor font from Inconsolata to Consolas the problem was fixed. Found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=505257) solution connect.microsoft

Comment: I haven't, but it sounds like you should report it on "connect".

Comment: You have or haven't seen this on previous versions of VS2010?

Comment: I have seen this on previous versions of VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a pretty fatal error in a fundamental operation, so it's unlikely to be a simple bug that was overlooked - it's more likely to be a problem with your install - If it were me, I would try reinstalling it (and do so with the default options - if the install was customised it's vaguely possible that a required component was not installed)

Comment: I agree. I'm using the same setup (VS2010 + win7) and I have never haid said problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to put a style element on an .ascx page.  Lots of times you can solve the error by saving the file, closing the page, then re-opening it.